# GLM and GAM modelling in RStudio

Tags: r, model, gam, mgcv

I have a question in GAM and GLM modelling in rstudio. Looking at results, each first factor stays in intercept, how do I stop that, so I can see all factor effects?
Thanks
Dave

Comment: Please be a bit more elaborate

Comment: model ran:
glm(y ~ offset(log(Effort)) + as.factor(Year) + as.factor(Month) + 
    as.factor(Season) + s(SST))
calling my model, results don't show the first parameters (e.g first month, first Year). I was told they automatically are included in intercept. How do I change that?

Comment: `+ 0` or `- 1` in your model formula.